# Initializing references in the constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constructor

I am working on a game project, and my teammate has a certain way of solving our reference issues, and it works great, except, when the game is big, we will end up with massive constructors.

```
class Player
{
   private:
      Weapon *w1, *w2, *w3;
      Armor *a1, *a2;

  public:
      Player(Weapon *w1, Weapon *w2, ...) : w1(w1), w2(w2), ...;
}
```

Then my constructor `is Player(w1, w2, w3, ...);` which is disturbing, what if the player class had 100 references?

Is there a way to make this syntax simpler, or are we doing it wrong? Is there a better way of making references to variables which are outside the player class?

**IMPORTANT**
The above is purely an example, a poorly written one. I don't just have weapons and armors. I have a ton of classes. I have a developer console reference, I have armor references, items, I have references to the debugging class, the logger class, and the list goes on. A vector is not helpful for me. Sorry for the poor example.

Comment: If you need to pass tens (or more) arguments, then you most likely is doing something wrong. Let the constructor(s) initialize member variables to some sane default value, and just change the few that really need to be changed.

Comment: As for this case, have you considered [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of discreet variables? If you use inheritance then it might be enough to have a single vector for *all* equipment, no matter the kind.

Comment: And a last comment, and just to nitpick, but in C++ you are not initializing references, you are initializing *pointers*. References in C++ is something different.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Read my edit

Comment: If any class has hundreds of member variables, then you almost certainly just have a really poor design, and should come up with a better one, then your problem will go away.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `vectors` ?

```
std::vector<Weapon *> W;
std::vector<Armor *> A;
```

Comment: Because weapon and armor was just an example. I have weapons, armor, tools, the developer console, and so many classes. Most of them have unique members, so a vector is in no way a solution for me :/

Comment: @ZamriMalakun then I'd say the example is not sufficient to point out to a specific data structure/stl container

Comment: @ZamriMalakun: You might consider using polymorphism. Should all different equipment derive from a common `Equipment` class, you could store them within a single container. If you need to quickly select some "type" of equipment, you can create an `enum` to distinguish the different kinds and create a `std::map<Equipment::Kind, std::vector<Equipment*>>` to hold onto all equipment pieces and still have a way to get all weapons or all armors without going over the whole equipment list.

Comment: @MatthieuM. +1 exactly that should be approach

Comment: @MatthieuM., I can't just make an interface for EVERY class in the game, that example only works if the player only has armors and weapons, but as I already stated, I have dozens of classes in my player that I must reference, polymorphism might not work here :/

Comment: @ZamriMalakun: I am afraid you are quite mistaken, I was simply suggesting that all those classes inherit from the same **one** base (even indirectly), not that you care an interface for each and every kind!

Comment: @ZamriMalakun A class is an interface and an interface is a class. That's exactly the key issue here. You need to design reusable interfaces to factor the monolithic class into maintainable chunks. (There will be more issues than just the constructor parameter list, but they will tend to follow the pattern of bloated randomness.)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed put it all in a single vector, if you use inheritance.

For a fantasy-themed game (which I assume you're writing) it could be something like this:

```
// The base object, contains common attributes
class Object { ... };

// The item class
class Item : public Object { ... };

class Weapon : public Item { ... };

class Sword : public Weapon { ... };

class Clothing : public Item { ... }

class Armour : public Clothing { ... };
```

Then it's enough with *one* vector for *all* equipment:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>> inventory;
```

For worn stuff, you could have separate variables, like

```
std::shared_ptr<Weapon> wielded;
std::shared_ptr<Clothing> head;  // Helmets, hats, etc.
```

Or use a map for the equipped stuff:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Item>> equipped;
```

Then you can use e.g.

```
equipped["wielded"]
```

to get the wielded item.

---

For completeness, some other possible classes in the class tree above might be:

```
class Character : public Object { ... }

class Player : public Character { ... }

class Monster : public Character { ... }

class Dragon : public Monster { ... }

class RedDragon : public Dragon { ... }

class TheUltimateBossDragon : public RedDragon { ... }
```

As a side note, I have used hierarchies like the above in my own games previously. However in my next game (when and *if* I get that far) I will probably use another pattern, where classes indicates behavior. For example, a `sword` is `equipable`, it's a `damage_inflicter`, it's `takeable`, etc. This means more complex inheritance hierarchies, with much more multiple inheritance, and will probably use RTTI more. But on the bright side it will hopefully be more flexible.

Comment: Important note for a beginner: it's enough **only** if `Object` or `Item` has a public `virtual` destructor.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a fixed number of pointers to a small number of types, try using vectors:

```
class Player
{
   private:
      std::vector<Weapon*> weapons;
      std::vector<Armor*> armors;

  public:
      Player(const std::vector<Weapon*>&, const std::vector<Armor*>&);
}
```